# Customizing a pivot_wider and collapsing rows

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| ID | Feature | Quality | Quantity | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Shed | A | 1 | AV |
| 72 | Masonry |  | 1 |  |
| 72 | Shed | D | 1 | AV |

Currently the data frame has the unit of observation as the feature, not the ID number. I would like to pivot this to a data frame that looks like this :

| ID | ShedQuant | ShedQual | ShedCond | MasonryQuant | MasonryQual | MasonryCond |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 | A | AV |  |  |  |
| 72 | 1 | D | AV | 1 |  |  |

In the new data frame, the unit of observation should be the ID number (aka each ID number is one row that lists all features associated with the ID number, and their quantities/qualities/conditions.

I tried to combine several pivot_widers but it did not give me the intended result. Any help is appreciated!

Note: If the quantity of a certain feature is more than 1 for a certain ID, I want a sum for the quantity column and blanks for quality and condition.

Comment: Hellow Rachel, can you share a code fragment? it would be appreciated if you can share the dataframe. i. e. if your example data.frame is df, paste the output of `dput(df)`

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(21L, 72L, 72L),
           Feature = c("Shed", "Masonry", "Shed"),
           Quality = c("A", NA, "D"),
          Quantity = c(1L, 1L, 1L),
         Condition = c("AV", NA, "AV")
) %>%
  pivot_wider(ID, names_from = Feature, names_glue = "{Feature}_{.value}",
              values_from = Quality:Condition, names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
     ID Shed_Quality Shed_Quantity Shed_Condition Masonry_Quality Masonry_Quantity Masonry_Condition
  <int> <chr>                <int> <chr>          <chr>                      <int> <chr>            
1    21 A                        1 AV             NA                            NA NA               
2    72 D                        1 AV             NA                             1 NA
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Seems to be just what I needed, but I'm getting errors trying to sort and examine the data now, something about "Error in max(wider_sfyi_3$RS1_SfyiQuantity) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument". Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like your real data might have a different structure than the example data, perhaps with nested variable(s).